# ftp_nlist returning an empty array for a non-empty directory

Tags: php, recursion, ftp

Hello everyone please i have a recursive function that fetch the ftp dir and files, but i can't get the content of some folders for example the test folder 
/public_html/**test**/myfiles.html     i don't get what inside the **test** otherwise the function works fine.

this is my code :

```
function ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $path, $parentId = null) {
static $cnt = 0;
$files = array();
$contents = ftp_nlist($ftpConnection, $path);

    foreach($contents as $currentFile) {
        $currentFileArray = array();
                $filesize = ftp_size($ftpConnection, $currentFile);
        $currentFileArray["text"] = $currentFile;
        $currentFileArray["parent_id"] = $parentId;
        $currentFileArray["id"] = $cnt++;
                $currentFileArray["filesize"] = NULL;
                if($filesize >= 0)
                    $currentFileArray["filesize"] = $filesize; // octets
        // assuming its a folder if there's no dot in the name
        if (strpos($currentFile, '.') === false)
            $currentFileArray["children"] = $this->ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $currentFile, $currentFileArray["id"]);
        $files [] = $currentFileArray;
    }
        return array_reverse($files) ;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP FTP ftp\_nlist not working, returning boolean false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219322/php-ftp-ftp-nlist-not-working-returning-boolean-false)

Comment: maybe, just some sub-folders not all

Comment: So you do not have a problem with the recursive function, right? You have a problem with listing few specific directories. So show us a simple code that explicitly lists that one problematic directory.

Comment: for example : i have a folder "Parent" contain another folder "Child".
when i move a file name "index.html" from / root.  to /parent/child/index.html it works fine i get the result BUT WHEN I RENAME THIS LAST ONE /child/**index.html**  from index.html to **default.html** or **yourname.html**
i don't get any result it's crazy

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on passive mode like on this post
[ftp_nlist command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609140/ftp-nlist-command-not-working/1612323)

```
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
$files_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, ".");
```

Comment: OP cannot get contents of **some** folders only. If the problem was with transfer mode, OP would not be able to retrieve any folder. Also `ftp_nlist` would return `false`, not "empty array", if the problem was with transferring of the listing.

Comment: I found the following comment on php.net for ftp_nlist may help ...
I noticed that this function won't work if working path is different, because $dir keeps value of whole path string. That's why adding basename()-function strips the path and this function will work also sub folders, not only in root folder.

function ftp_is_dir($dir) {
  global $ftp_connect;
  if (ftp_chdir($ftp_connect, basename($dir))) {
    ftp_chdir($ftp_connect, '..');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

ftp_nlist returns empty array if no space left in tmp folder